# Python to return multiple different strings that all begin with the same character

Tags: python, string, slice

I am trying to get python to print out every single occurrence of the character '@' and an undetermined number of characters that comes after it in a .txt document. Not sure if I need to split the entire document up by ' ' and put it into a list, then slice the list? I'm extremely new to all programming.

This is what I've tried, among lots of other stuff that was even more off base than this.

```
import re

#open negativetweets and name it tweets_obj
with open('negative_tweets.txt') as tweets_obj:
    string=tweets_obj.read().replace('/n', '')

wordlist=[]

for word in string:
    wordlist.append(word)


re.match('@', wordlist)
```

Comment: It would be useful to provide some sample data, and input/output scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you're trying to get all user mentions here. splitting tweets with a space sounds right to start with. you could simply use startswith('@') to look for words beginning with '@'

```
string=tweets_obj.read().replace('\n', ' ')
mentions = []
mentions.append(i for i in string.split(' ') if i.startswith('@'))
```

the mentions list should contain all "words" starting with a "@"

Comment: Note that removing the linefeeds means that an `@` mention at the end of what used to be a line will now run into the next - e.g., `hi @user\nhi` will turn into `hi @userhi`, finding a user of `@userhi`.

Comment: edited. replacing the '\n' with a space ' ' instead of '' should solve this issue.

Comment: There's no need for a `replace` at all. This can be one line, `mentions = [word for word in tweets_obj.read().split() if word.startswith('@')]`.

Comment: Oh, and the code block you have now isn't creating the object you think it is (appending a generator).